# Object loses all functions after Dialog.open

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Javascript object that (very simplified) looks like this

```
if('undefined' !== typeof(listCtrls)){ for (ctrlName in listCtrls) {
var ctrl = listCtrls[ctrlName];

ctrl.Initialize = function() {
    //Save a reference to the 'tbody' element
    this.tbody = $("#"+this.id+"_tbody");
    this.dataFetched = false;
}
ctrl.Update = function(command){
    //Go and fetch some data
    $.post(url, function(ssResponse){ ... }
    this.tbody = "fill with AJAX data";
}
ctrls.SomeMoreFunctionsAsWell() {}
}});
```

As you can see in function `Initialize()`, it have a reference to a HTML element.
Everything is working great until I place the referenced HTML elements inside a JQuery dialog.

As soon as the dialog opens, `ctrl` loses all its functions. And I cant understand why! It would have made sense if something went wrong when `Dialog.Destroy()` is called, but this error happens directly after the dialog is opened.

Now, I don't get an regular javascript error during `Dialog.Open()`. Rather I get an error when i click on a element inside the dialog which calls `ctrl.Update()`.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'Update

HTML code:

```
<div id="dialog_Substitute" style="display:none;" title="test">
    <div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="style"></span>
<table style="width:100%" id="substitutelist_table">
<thead id="substitutelist_thead"><tr><th style="cursor: pointer; ">Name</th><th style="cursor: pointer; ">Valid from</th><th style="cursor: pointer; ">Valid through</th><th style="cursor: pointer; ">Incl. Authorities</th><th style="cursor: pointer; "></th></tr></thead>
<tbody class="tbodydata" id="substitutelist_tbody">
<tr style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><td class="left" style="">Lager, Patrik</td><td class="left" style="">2011-04-15</td><td class="left" style="">2011-07-01</td><td class="left" style=""></td><td class="action left" onclick="if(¤7¤==true) {var a=¤6¤; var b='2011-04-15'; deleteItem(a,b);};return kill(event);" style=""><img src="../Styles\sctrls/delete_16.png" alt="Ta bort"></td></tr>
<tr style=""><td class="left" style="">Svensson, Marie</td><td class="left" style="">2011-04-15</td><td class="left" style="">2011-05-12</td><td class="left" style=""></td><td class="action left" onclick="if(¤7¤==true) {var a=¤6¤; var b='2011-04-15'; deleteItem(a,b);};return kill(event);" style=""><img src="../Styles/sctrls/delete_16.png" alt="Ta bort"></td></tr>
<tr style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><td class="left" style="">Lind, Linda</td><td class="left" style="">2011-02-05</td><td class="left" style="">2011-02-27</td><td class="left" style=""></td><td class="action left" onclick="if(¤7¤==true) {var a=¤6¤; var b='2011-02-05'; deleteItem(a,b);};return kill(event);" style=""><img     src="../Styles/sctrls/delete_16.png" alt="Ta bort"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
    </div>
```

JS code that opens the dialog:

```
function dialogSubstitutes(user_id, user_name)
{
    //list ID=substitutelist
    //dialog ID =dialog_Substitute

    //Reset form (it might have been used before)
    //$("#frm_newsubstitute")[0].reset();

    //Fetch substitutes for this user and populate the List
    listCtrls["substitutelist"].dataSrcParams.user_id = user_id;
    listCtrls["substitutelist"].Update(-1);


    $("#dialog_Substitute").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
            'OK': function() {
                $("#dialog_Substitute").dialog('close');
                //$("#dialog_Substitute").dialog('destroy');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

thanks!

Comment: I see no dialog call anywhere in your code

Comment: Ah yes, your right. (now included)

Comment: where is `listCtrls` coming from?

Comment: listCtrls["substitutelist"] === ctrl

Comment: @David where in the code do u state that???

Comment: I included that as well above now. Sorry for not posting all the code, but I thought it would just make it harder to read.

Comment: for (ctrlName in listCtrls) {
    var ctrl = listCtrls[ctrlName];

Comment: @David, i see no updated post...

Comment: @Neal, in the topmost code section, the first two lines. Its a FOR loop that builds up the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (love that expression) that when a `JQuery.Dialog()` is opened, not only does it move the innerHTML code of the dialog, it also executes any inline javascript code.

And because the ctrl had its initializer code placed right beside, it was executed a 2nd time and thus, it lost data.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the top code:

```
if ('undefined' !== typeof (listCtrls))
{
  for (ctrlName in listCtrls)
  {

    listCtrls[ctrlName].Initialize = function ()
    {
      //Save a reference to the 'tbody' element
      this.tbody = $("#" + this.id + "_tbody");
      this.dataFetched = false;
    }
    listCtrls[ctrlName].Update = function (command)
    {
      //Go and fetch some data
      $.post(url, function (ssResponse)
      {...
      }
      this.tbody = "fill with AJAX data";
      }
      listCtrls[ctrlName].SomeMoreFunctionsAsWell = function ()
      {}
    }
  }
}
```

You were never defining anything outside the scope.

Comment: sorry, it got lost while shortening the function. I'll fix it

Comment: yep. The object is a ListControl that is used in many places in my website. And it works great. But this is the first time I placed it inside a JQuery.Dialog

Comment: @Neal. Thanks for your incredible commitment to make this work. Your right that I dont define 'ctrl' outside the scope. But inside, ctrl equals listCtrols[ctrlname] thanks to this row: var ctrl = listCtrls[ctrlName]

Comment: it doesnt though, that `ctrl` variable is not available out of the scope.

Comment: @Neal, maybe I misunderstood you. The Array called 'listCtrls' is already defined before this, and it contains an object called 'substitutelist'. Thats what the FOR loop iterates over.

Comment: YES. but `ctrl` is only defined in the scope, and that is the variable you are attaching those functions to. not `listCtrls`

Comment: We´re gonna write a whole novel soon Neal :)

Comment: Well im done soon. did you try using my update or are you going to keep complaining how urs works (even though we both know it does not)

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. But I think ctrl & listCtrls[substitutelist] reference the same object. And it actually works as long as no Jquery.Dialog() is involved.

Comment: Im Sorry, Im not that good in english.  What I meant is that the code is well proven to work in 15+ different pages. So I think we are stuck on the wrong questions. I think we should try to focus on why listCtrls[substitutelist] loses all its functions after a Query.Dialog() has been called.

Answer (score 0):

When a jQuery dialog is created the html it is moved out of the body! This is probably where your problem is stemming from...

Comment: Do you think that because the tbody-reference is no longer valid, CTRL loses all of its functions (including Update()  ?

Comment: I updated all functions of CTRL to reset the reference to the TBODY element. Still the same error though :(

Answer (score 0):

I can' find where you call DialogSubstitutes method.
But I solved same problem with a simple line, if you are calling a jquery function with a link or button, that link or button keeps doing his DOM work, so you must avoid that work, like stop it.

Jquery has a method called e.preventDefault() that does the trick, default action for links is to go to the top of the page, with e.preventDefault() page will stay where it is.

but you must change the way you call your functions to this way:

```
$(".SomeButtonOrLinkOrDomObjectId").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault(); //this does the trick.

    //then, your code...

});
```

hope it helps.

Bye.